# Is it safe to store Developer's Consumer Secret in Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, security, oauth

I am currently developing a **iOS** app using **Swift 4.1**.

As my app involves the Twitter REST API, I need to provide the consumer key and consumer secret in one of my classes. (i.e developer's consumer key and secret, users DO NOT need to generate their own key)

Would like to know if it is **safe** to store the consumer key and consumer secret in the code or do I need to store them somewhere else?

Comment: You could probably store in your secure server and fetch it runtime and then store in KeyChain. Revoke/Renew it periodically and make the app to fetch new ones

Comment: is it possible that ppl download my app and reverse engineer the app to get my API keys in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if it's valuable enough, any secret will eventually be compromised. The trick is to make it harder to steal than the benefit that would result from stealing it.

Specifying your API key as a string constant is a pretty bad idea. A hacker with access to the binary or intermediate bitcode could extract strings from the binary and look for high entropy constants which are likely candidates to be API key values.

Be careful, it is also very easy to store your secret in your git repository and accidentally publish it for the world to see.

As an improvement, consider obfuscating the API key in your code and computing the actual key value at runtime. For example, use a simple exclusive-or mask:

```
MaskedApiKey = OriginalApiKey XOR Mask

OriginalApiKey = MaskedApiKey XOR Mask
```

Store the MaskedApiKey and Mask in your code, and combine them at runtime to restore the OriginalApiKey. Now an attacker needs to grab two constants from your code to steal the API key. You can extend this technique to make it arbitrarily obfuscated at runtime. The logical extension of this is [white box encryption](https://www.arxan.com/arxan-blog/leverage-white-box-cryptography-and-tamper-resistance-to-advance-api-protection)

A secret is even harder to steal if it is never stored in your code in the first place. So, an alternative technique is to store the API key in an external secrets service off your app. By registering your app with the secrets service, the service can attest that the app is authentic and untampered and provide your app the API key at run time. See [Mobile API Security](https://www.approov.io/blog/mobile-api-security-techniques-part-2.html) toward the end of the article for an example.

Of course, none of this matters if your API call is made in the clear and is easily observed by a [Man in the Middle (MitM) attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Always make your API calls using TLS 
(HTTPS) strengthened by [certificate pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).

Take a look at this [OWASP talk](https://hackernoon.com/a-tour-of-api-underprotection-2ad86fc5ce48) for a quick overview of mobile API security.